# Rebind just `C-c` to some command

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys

I'd like to rebind `C-c` to `eshell-interrupt-process`, so I don't need to press `C-c C-c`. I tried the naive

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'something)
```

And similar commands but when I press `C-c` emacs waits for me to finish the combo, instead of just executing `something`.

Why is this happening? How can I bind just `C-c` to some command?

Answer (score 2):

That is not so easy, because C-c is a general prefix key in Emacs. Here is a hacky way to achieve that, don't know if there are better options:

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'my-hacky-C-c-remap)

(defun my-hacky-C-c-remap ()
  (setq-local key-translation-map
              (copy-keymap key-translation-map))
  ;; choose any key you dont use for translation
  (define-key key-translation-map [?\C-c] (kbd "<f10>"))
  (local-set-key (kbd "<f10>") 'eshell-interrupt-process))
```